# Turn signal malfunction, is it multifunction switch or the flasher relay should be replaced?

Tags: electrical, jeep, grand-cherokee

I am having a similar problem on my 2007 Jeep Grand Cherokee Laredo, and the problem is:

```
Stalk left: left/right all off
Stalk neutral: left on
Stalk right: left on.
```

I will try the same trick and to see what gonna happen.

Seems like a bad symptom for 2007 Jeep...

Checked several forums and found out two quick solutions: replace a) multifunction switch b) flasher relay. Kinda confused right now, needs some help.

Comment: I think this would point to the multi-function switch, but not entirely sure.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, just talked to my friend who has a bit mechanic experience, he said the same thing, will try to replace a new multi-function swtich anyway, though this is a small problem but very annoying

Comment: The multi-function switches usually don't cost too much. You can get them on the internet fairly easily as well.

Comment: Yes, problem solved, the malfunction of the multi-function switch, replaced with a new one and it worked.